# Can't fetch properties from spring-cloud-config using release Brixton.M3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I created some sample spring cloud applications to use eureka and the config-server. Within a fancy-server component I'm trying to using the configuration property which is configured in the config-server in a database.yml. I'm using the Brixton.M3 release which was created via start.spring.io page.

- Starting eureka-server seems to be fine.
- Starting the config-server seems to be fine as well (config-server is available in eureka, checked with http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps).
- But when I start the fancy-server which uses a property from config-server it fails with 'unresolveable property error' message.

So what's wrong? A bug in Brixton.M3?

My code is available on github: https://github.com/mirwais27/spring-cloud-evaluation

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Cloud Config Server in your *fancy-server/src/main/resources/application.yml*:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: fancyserver
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: Adding the uri as suggested did not helped. I added also to the bootstrap.yml of the fancyserver without any success. Beside that I found out that there is also the option to let the fancyserver 'find' the configserver via eureka with this `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true`, as described in http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config_client But this was also not working - even I can see that the configserver is registered in eureka.

Comment: it actually needs to go in bootstrap.yml.

Comment: If you want properties for every client, put them in `application.yml` in the config server, otherwise it's `<appname>-<springprofile>.yml`. That's why nothing is seeing database.yml, there's no app named `database`.